# Are TO-220 and TO-247 MOSFET heatsinks compatible?

Tags: heatsink, to220

Are TO-220 and TO-247 MOSFET heatsinks compatible?

Comment: Not generally. TO-220 and TO-247 are differently sized.

Comment: Probably depends on the heatsink, do you have some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general, but it is possible.

While the mount-holes are approximately the same size, the TO-247 is larger than the TO-220.

The problems you will run into:

A heatsink made for TO-247 when used on a TO-220 will likely interfere with the PCB if the mount hole is lined up, as it will be too long.  This can be mitigated by mounting the TO-220 higher (i.e. not all the way seated).

A heatsink made for TO-220 used on a TO-247 will likely be too narrow and/or too short to be fully effective.  This could work if your heatsinking requirements are not too critical.

Edit: As pointed out in comments by Hearth, there exists heatsinks made to work with both.  [One Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H5GQVTD)

**TO-220 Dimensions:**

[image: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v3/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/package-detail/Pkg_pkgdim/TO-220-2L_pkgdim.gif]

[Image Source](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v3/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/package-detail/Pkg_pkgdim/TO-220-2L_pkgdim.gif)

**TO-247 Dimensions:**

[image: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v3/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/package-detail/Pkg_pkgdim/TO-247-4L_pkgdim.png]

[Image Source](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v3/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/package-detail/Pkg_pkgdim/TO-247-4L_pkgdim.png)

Comment: There are a number of heatsinks, both clip-on and screw-mount, that are explicitly made to be compatible with both TO-220 and TO-247 (and sometimes TO-264), too.

Comment: Thank you @Hearth, I have added your comment to the answer.